# Is it possible to implement collection literal initializers for custom classes in Groovy?

Tags: collections, groovy, literals

For example LibGDX framework has custom made collection classes such as `Array<T>` and `ObjectMap<K, V>` which aid app/game performance. Would it be possible to create a literal initializer so that `Array` could be initialized with for example `[1,2,3,4]` and `ObjectMap` with `[key:"value"]`.

I know that access operators `[]` can be added to objects by implementing `putAt`/`getAt` methods but haven't seen anything about literal initializers.

Are they locked down into the language itself like operator overriding is in Java or is there a way to create list/map initializers for custom classes?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: i think OP wants to get an ObjectMap from something like `[x:42]` instead of a `LinkedHashMap` (and my guess is, that this is impossible).  @MrPlow you can at least get rid of some repetition with `with`.

Comment: Would `[x:42] as ObjectMap` not work?

Comment: @tim_yates by adding an asType for it on LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Depends how `ObjectMap` is implemented... I'll have a look when I get a chance

Comment: @tim_yates as @cfrick said I'm wondering if there is a way to initialize custom classes using Map/List literals. As an example I've mentioned [ObjectMap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ObjectMap.html). It implements Java's `Iterable` if that's worth anything.

Comment: Added a couple of options...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible method is to manipulate the existing `LinkedHashMap.asType()` method to accept `ObjectMap` as a parameter:

```
def originalMethod = LinkedHashMap.getMetaClass().getMetaMethod("asType", Class)
LinkedHashMap.getMetaClass().asType = { Class clazz ->
    if(clazz == ObjectMap) {
        def map = new ObjectMap()
        delegate.each { key, value -> map.put(key, value) }
        map
    }
    else {
        originalMethod.invoke(delegate, clazz)
    }
}
```

You can then do:

```
def map = [a:1] as ObjectMap
```

Another option would be to add a method `toObjectMap()` to the base `Map` metaClass like so:

```
Map.getMetaClass().toObjectMap = { ->
    def map = new ObjectMap()
    delegate.each { key, value -> map.put(key, value) }
    map
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
def map2 = [a:2].toObjectMap()
```

Or, just write a utility method to convert Maps to ObjectMaps ;-)

Comment: I see. Though the downside of this is that there will always be two allocations. One for the temporary LinkedHashMap (which will soon after leave scope and get flagged for GC) and one for ObjectMap. I guess that's something I'll have to accept (it's not like I'll use literal maps every tick). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ease of use always comes with a cost ;-)

Comment: To extend on Tim's answer. If the class provides a constructor where each element of the list fits in (for example with Object[]/Object...), then a line like `ObjectMap map2 = [1,2,3]` will work. This will still create an intermediate LinkedHashMap, but future version of Groovy may optimize on this.